# Elasticsearch: Get documents which have minimum matching percentage

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider I have following two documents indexed:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "name": "John A"
    }
]
```

The match percentage of the word `John` is 50 and 66.7 with the field `name` of the first and second document respectively.

Now the question is, how can I find all the matches, where the match percentage is more than X, where `0<=X<=100`. Match should be always prefix match.

Comment: have you seen minimum_should_match parameter: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15521 you can use also percentage https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html

Comment: `minimum_should_match` is either for the number of boolean should or the number of tokens in a query, but not for the number of matching characters.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see to do it is the use of a [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-script-query.html) in a filter to determine a minimum length of the field (you can calculate it with your percentage and your term length):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            // Your name: 'John' match
            {
              "script": {                    
                "script": {  
                  "params": {
                    "min_size": 4
                  },
                  // In ES <5.6 versions, use "inline" instead of "source"
                  "source": "doc['name'].values.length() > params.min_size" 
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But you will have to [enable fielddata on your field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_enabling_fielddata_on_literal_text_literal_fields).

Answer (score 0):

While you can build something like this with scripting (as [Julien TASSIN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6299938/julien-tassin) describes), this is not what you want:

1. Unless you have a filter criteria or very little data, this will be slow, since Elasticsearch needs to do some heavy calculations for every search.
2. Elasticsearch generally operates on tokens. While you can do a lot of things with scripting, your use case sounds like you are either using it wrong or Elasticsearch is probably not a great fit; though I don't know any other system that would work very well for this specific requirement.